# get no. of lines printed for a date range

Tags: linux, bash, date, awk, sed

I am trying to get the count of no. of lines printed for a given date range.

Here is my input and output:

```
grep -inr "\[HSM \]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" *ActNac*
ActNacd.txt:47:2017-01-02 09:10:13 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-20_20-39-18.txt:171:2016-12-19 13:23:48 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-20_20-39-18.txt:217:2016-12-19 14:27:26 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-26_09-44-47.txt:47:2016-12-25 19:26:13 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-26_09-44-47.txt:91:2016-12-25 20:30:38 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-27_07-32-25.txt:47:2016-12-26 11:08:28 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-27_18-06-29.txt:47:2016-12-27 07:35:55 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-30_08-22-16.txt:48:2016-12-28 18:04:19 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2017-01-02_06-56-52.txt:47:2016-12-30 08:24:19 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2017-01-02_09-07-23.txt:47:2017-01-02 06:59:33 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
```

I want to find the no. of lines printed from date 2017-12-20 to 2017-12-30.

Start date and End date are not confirmed, so if i use sed command like

```
grep -inr "\[HSM \]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" *ActNac* | sed -n '/2016-12-20/,/2017-12-27/p'"
```

but if i provide input like:

```
grep -inr "\[HSM \]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" *ActNac* | sed -n '/2016-12-19/,/2017-12-27/p'"
```

It does not give any output, since the start date does not match with any of the lines as input date. There are no log files with date 2016-12-19.

Is there any other way with sed/awk/grep command to get the no of lines, on a range of input dates.

Comment: To get the number of lines output from anything, just pipe the output to `wc -l`.

Comment: I have to filter out the proper lines from 20-27/12 then to get count i would use wc -l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` alone for this.

To get the count alone,

```
awk -F'[: ]' '$3 >= "2016-12-16" && $3 <= "2016-12-26 && NR>1"{count++;}END{print count}' newfile
5
```

To get the actual logs, I have used dates not actually present in the log,

```
awk -F'[: ]' '$3 >= "2016-12-22" && $3 <= "2016-12-29" && NR>1' newfile
old_ActNacd_2016-12-26_09-44-47.txt:47:2016-12-25 19:26:13 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-26_09-44-47.txt:91:2016-12-25 20:30:38 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-27_07-32-25.txt:47:2016-12-26 11:08:28 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-27_18-06-29.txt:47:2016-12-27 07:35:55 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
old_ActNacd_2016-12-30_08-22-16.txt:48:2016-12-28 18:04:19 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
```

To get the count, use `{count++;}END{print count}` clause as in the first command.

Comment: it should have print only 4 since there only 4 logs(2 logs for 2016-12-26 and 2 logs for 2016-12-27). But it's printing 10 i.e the no. of lines present for input file.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. In the above figure it should not have included the log for 2016-12-30, since we the end date is 2016-12-29. Likewise the if startdate is 2016-12-19 then only logs of 2016-12-20 are included. The answer is very close. Could you please include any boundary conditions to check for it.  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @SantoshSahu: Refer my update, your ^ above comment does not seem correct, recheck again with the dates and observe the output.

Comment: @Inlan I have edited the comments. Hope this time you would find more readable:

Thanks for the effort. In the above figure it should not have included the log for 2016-12-30, since the end date is 2016-12-29. Likewise if the startdate is 2016-12-19, then only logs of 2016-12-20 are included, but if we provide start date as 2016-12-20, logs for 2016-12-20 are not considered. The answer is very close. Could you please include any boundary conditions to check for it.  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @SantoshSahu: Which log are you referring to ? `2016-12-30` is not present in my output of my `awk`, tell me which command is causing that output.

Comment: @Inlan If i run the command "grep -inr "\[HSM \]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" *ActNac* | awk -F'[: ]' '$3 >= "2016-12-26" && $3 < "2016-12-30" && NR>=1'" then the logs for 2016-12-26 are not displayed, i think we have to change some boundary condition.

Again appreciate your effort. Thanks!!!

Comment: @SantoshSahu: Can you update the output for `grep -inr "[HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" ActNac` in the question for which you say the awk command is not working? Can you update it as part of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132121/discussion-between-inian-and-santosh-sahu).

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty you are having has nothing to do with counting lines (that's easy, just pipe the data to `wc -l`), but with comparing dates.  If you want to compare dates, the simplest thing to do is to convert them to a reasonable representation which make comparisons easy.  eg, epoch time.  A simple way to do that with perl:

```
perl -mTime::Piece -ne 'm/[^:]*:[^:]*:([-0-9]*) /; 
    $t=Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d"); print if $t > 1482192000;' input
```

This will print the lines in which the date is past 1482192000 (midnight GMT on Dec 20).  To count them, either count them in perl:

```
perl -mTime::Piece -nE 'm/[^:]*:[^:]*:([-0-9]*) /; 
    $t=Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d"); $v++ if $t > 1482192000;
    END{say $v}' input
```

or just pipe to wc:

```
perl -mTime::Piece -ne 'm/[^:]*:[^:]*:([-0-9]*) /; 
    $t=Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d"); print if $t > 1482192000;' input | 
wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

When all lines have a date string, you can do something like
`grep -Ec "^2016-12-2" *ActNac*` (until 2016-12-30 excluding the 30th),

or

```
grep -Ec "^2016-12-(2|30)" *ActNac*
```